# Create custom page templates with plugins?

Tags: plugins, templates, page-template

Is it possible to make custom page templates available from a plugin?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[`get_page_template()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/theme.php#L917) can be overridden via the `page_template` filter. If your plugin is a directory with the templates as files in them, it's just a matter of passing the names of these files. If you want to create them "on the fly" (edit them in the admin area and save them in the database?), you might want to write them to a cache directory and refer to them, or hook into [`template_redirect`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/template-loader.php) and do some crazy `eval()` stuff.

A simple example for a plugin that "redirects" to a file in the same plugin directory if a certain criterium is true:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'my-custom-page-slug' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/custom-page-template.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Comment: Hey Jan, do you have some example code on how to pass a plugin file in as a custom page template?

Comment: @trnsfrmr: It's really easy, I added a simple example to my answer.

Comment: Note that this has been more or less replaced by the "template_include" filter in later versions (3.1+).

Comment: Perfect !!!, you have save my time @JanFabry

Comment: As stated by @fireydude, this is not a generic solution. It's a workaround that hard-codes the page slug.

Answer (score 30):

Overriding `get_page_template()` is just a quick hack. It does not allow the template to be selected from the Admin screen and the page slug is hard-coded into the plugin so the user has no way to know where the template is coming from.

**The preferred solution** would be to follow [this tutorial](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/) which allows you to register a page template in the back-end from the plug-in.  Then it works like any other template.

```
 /*
 * Initializes the plugin by setting filters and administration functions.
 */
private function __construct() {
        $this->templates = array();

        // Add a filter to the attributes metabox to inject template into the cache.
        add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args',
            array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
        );

        // Add a filter to the save post to inject out template into the page cache
        add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 
            array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
        );

        // Add a filter to the template include to determine if the page has our 
        // template assigned and return it's path
        add_filter('template_include', 
            array( $this, 'view_project_template') 
        );

        // Add your templates to this array.
        $this->templates = array(
                'goodtobebad-template.php'     => 'It\'s Good to Be Bad',
        );
}
```

Comment: Would be nice (*and prefered*) if you can post the relevant code from the link in your answer, otherwise this is nothing more than a bloated comment :-)

Comment: The tutorial actually credits [Tom McFarlin's example](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/page-template-example) as the originator of this approach.

Answer (score 15):

None of the previous answers was working for me. Here one where you can choose your template in Wordpress admin. Just put it in your main php plugin file and change `template-configurator.php` by your template name

```
//Load template from specific page
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template ){

    if ( get_page_template_slug() == 'template-configurator.php' ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template-configurator.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}

/**
 * Add "Custom" template to page attirbute template section.
 */
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'wpse_288589_add_template_to_select', 10, 4 );
function wpse_288589_add_template_to_select( $post_templates, $wp_theme, $post, $post_type ) {

    // Add custom template named template-custom.php to select dropdown 
    $post_templates['template-configurator.php'] = __('Configurator');

    return $post_templates;
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible. I found this [example plugin](https://github.com/wpexplorer/page-templater) very helpful.

Another approach that is come into my head is using [WP Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) to create the template file to theme. I am not sure that it is the best approach to take, but I am sure it work!

Comment: The linked example plugin is even pretty well documented. I like that. :)