# Is there a WordPress plugin that registers a plugin file as a custom page template?

Tags: plugins, templates, page-template

I need to create a plugin that makes custom page templates available in wp-admin. I'm wondering if someone has tackled this already, as it seems like a pretty typical process?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You want a plugin that inserts custom templates defined in plugin?

Answer (score 8):

Like Rarst answered you can really do that without editing core files or remove the page attributes metabox and create your on using the same code with a bit of modification.
the code below is the code for the /admin/include/meta-boxes.php
and i added the a comment to show where your extra page template options would go:

```
function page_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
    if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => $post->post_type, 'exclude_tree' => $post->ID, 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
        ?>
        <p><strong><?php _e('Parent') ?></strong></p>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="parent_id"><?php _e('Parent') ?></label>
        <?php echo $pages; ?>
        <?php
        } // end empty pages check
    } // end hierarchical check.
    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type && 0 != count( get_page_templates() ) ) {
        $template = !empty($post->page_template) ? $post->page_template : false;
        ?>
        <p><strong><?php _e('Template') ?></strong></p>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label><select name="page_template" id="page_template">
        <option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
        <?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>

        // add your page templates as options

        </select>
        <?php
    } ?>
    <p><strong><?php _e('Order') ?></strong></p>
    <p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="menu_order"><?php _e('Order') ?></label><input name="menu_order" type="text" size="4" id="menu_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->menu_order) ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) _e( 'Need help? Use the Help tab in the upper right of your screen.' ); ?></p>
    <?php
}
```

Don't know if this is a fix in your case but i had a smiler case when i needed to display the post type in a plugin built-in theme and for that i used `add_filter('the_content', 'my-function');`
and my-function created the output to display.

Another option would be to make your plugin create the template file in the current theme directory , something like this:

```
function create_plugins_theme_file(){
    $file_name = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $tamplate_name . '.php';
    $handle = fopen($file_name, 'w') or wp_die('Cannot open file for editing');
    $file_contents = <<<OUT
<?php
/*
Template Name: $tamplate_name
*/
?>

//you theme file here

OUT;

   fwrite($handle, $file_contents);
   fclose($handle);
 }
```

and you can run this after you first check if the file exist

```
if(!file_exists( $file_name)){create_plugins_theme_file();}
```

Hope one of this helps.

Comment: Will test meta box stuff, bus as per my answer - it's only part of issue, other is - code that tries to load template only if it's in theme directory. So providing "external" template file may not be sufficient to get it loaded.

Comment: that's why i suggested to make the plugin create the files in the theme's directory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, at least why you would want a plugin to do that.

The normal procedure for creating different page templates is:

1. Create a new page-template in your ACTIVE theme directory (make a copy of page.php).
2. Change the name of the template (inside the file).

   /* 
   Template Name: Full Width Page
   */
3. Change the code of the page to what you are trying to achieve.
4. You can now go create a new page and choose which "Template" to use.

[image]

...

I hope that is what you are trying to achieve?

Official documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Woops. sample PHP code is a bit messed up. Visit the link for proper code example.

Comment: Interested in knowing if anyone is using Jan's method in an existing plugin: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins/3558#3558

Comment: I believe @trnsfrmr is looking for a way how to create a pre-defined page template (steps 1-3) inside his own plugin to make this template available for users after the plugin activation. I suppose he wants to keep this solution theme independent.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood a bit there, thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be quite hard to achieve. `get_page_templates()` function actively discards anything that is not located in parent and child root directories. It also doesn't store in global variable or allow to filter generated list of templates.

I think page attributes meta box will need to be forked and completely replaced for this. And not sure it will be possible even then.

I agree that this seems like something that makes sense, but WordPress code is very precise in that it wants named templates to only come from theme's directory.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't doing this one of the reasons that `register_theme_directory()` got introduced?

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10467

At the time it was an issue related to BuddyPress, which wanted to toss in extra templates here and there.

I take it they're not properly listed as page templates, though:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15803

Comment: I will go over code (probably tomorrow), but as far as I remember templates with names are explicitly looked up through path constants only.