# Loading template files from a subfolder in my theme?

Tags: themes, filters, core, templates

I am working on a site that will have up to 30 templates in it.

I don't want to have all those templates at the root of my theme folder cluttering up everything.

I know how I can modify the `get_page_templates()` function in the file `wp-admin/includes/theme.php` to make it scan sub dirs in my theme folder. But I do not want to change core files manually - how can I apply a filter to `get_page_templates()` with a filter that I put in `functions.php` ?

As the code you see below is my first attempt at this but it doesn´t work yet when I put the code inside `function.php`.

I can however put these changes into the core file `wp-admin/includes/theme.php` but that is not good practice and should always be avoided right, as auto update can wipe it out.

```
function get_page_templates_override() 
{
$themes = get_themes();
$theme = get_current_theme();
$templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
$page_templates = array();

if ( is_array( $templates ) ) {
    $base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) );

    foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
        $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);

        // modifide this by commenting it out so that sub dirs arent blocked
        // if ( false !== strpos($basename, '/') )
        //  continue;

        // modified this with FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH so sub dirs get scanned
        $template_data = implode( '', file( $template, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH ));

        $name = '';
        if ( preg_match( '|Template Name:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name ) )
            $name = _cleanup_header_comment($name[1]);

        if ( !empty( $name ) ) {
            $page_templates[trim( $name )] = $basename;
        }
    }
}
return $page_templates;
}
add_filter('get_page_templates','get_page_templates_override', 1);
```

Comment: Ahmmm.. you're applying a filter to an non-existing filter hook 'get_page_templates'.

Comment: Yes I´ve been suspecting that there is no hook in the wp core system for this is that true?

Comment: Yeah, get_page_templates is 'just' a function without filters.

Comment: Hmm.. am trying to see where you could plug into a filter but aint really seeing where that would be possible..

Comment: Carrington theme framework does some very interesting things with template hierachy, maybe it would be worth looking there?

Answer (score 2):

That part is extremely rigid, see this [question about loading page templates from plugin directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/is-there-a-wordpress-plugin-that-registers-a-plugin-file-as-a-custom-page-templat).

With current state of related code I would not bother spending time on this. Especially since you want it for convenience (putting template in sub-directories) and not functionality (like loading from plugin folder).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tickets on this: [#13265](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13265) and [#11216](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11216).

Also, it looks less cluttered if you prefix each template with a fixed string:

```
template-a.php
template-b.php
```

etc.

Comment: Thnx for the response I ve already done this and that helps you can also move most tempalates parts into sub folders by using get_template_part('I put path to sub folder here', 'and file name here'). Pages can also be move into sub folders but to get them to show in admin page attributes I must modifiy the core file I pointed to above and that I want to avoid.

Comment: Or you could make your own page attributes metabox. It results in some code duplication, but at least it keeps core clean.

Comment: Good point If I render my own meta box and call my get_pages_templates_own function instead there is no worries ;-) I will try that instead thnx =)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that as of WP 3.4 (nearly a year ago) it is now possible to place *page* template files into a directory below the theme root and WordPress will detect and use them as needed.

As per http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/.