# wordpress template page Usage

Tags: themes, templates, pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading template files from a subfolder in my theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11798/loading-template-files-from-a-subfolder-in-my-theme)

How to create template page which is in a separate folder within theme directory, for pages and also to open it in other pages (i.e: link to those template pages.).

I have created a folder in my theme directory and inside it i also create a template page but no working.

Answer (score 0):

Template pages can only be found in the main directory of a theme. If you want to add template pages NOT found in the theme's main directory, you will need to use [this method](http://www.unfocus.com/2010/08/10/including-page-templates-from-a-wordpress-plugin/) and you will need to use it for each template.