# Best way to distribute templates and code accross multiple wordpress sites?

Tags: plugin-development, templates, page-template, plugin-recommendation

I am launching Christmas pages across 8 different websites which share almost the same code. What is the best way to distribute this?

The files include:

- christmas page
- style.css
- swipbox.js

At the moment, if I make a change in one of the files, i'd need to make it in all of them.

Would you advise creating a plugin for this?... suggestions?

Comment: You know it's August, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle the files into a plugin.

For the Christmas page, you could use the [`page_template` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template) - This question gives you an example on how to use it - [Create custom page templates with plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins)

For the CSS/JS file, you can add them using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), as you would normally use in a theme. The only difference is that you'll need to use [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) to link to the target files.

Finally, for updating the plugins easily, there are a bunch of libraries [like this one](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker) which allows you to have the *one click updates* for your plugins like you normally have for plugins hosted in the WordPress repositories.

Comment: Thanks! I think what i'll do is create a plugin to generate a unique page and use a custom template for that page.

Comment: With plguins, Is it possible to create a custom page and use the standard file formatting of page-mypage.php as the template for this page? and keep all the files within the plugin folder?

Comment: Yes it is possible, plugins like Woocommerce do that. You gotta research how it's done though.